# Error on Quoted String within ADOQuery in Delphi: `Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.`

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

I am having trouble with below ADOQuery quoted string %ABC%:

```
adoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
adoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM MyDB.MyTable WHERE MyField LIKE ''''%ABC%'''' ';
adoQuery1.ExecSQL;
adoQuery1.Close;
adoQuery1.Open;
```

I also tried to pass below parameter instead but no success:

```
adoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
adoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM MyDB.MyTable WHERE MyField LIKE :Param1 ';
aqBCCombi.Parameters.ParamByName('Param1').Value := '%ABC%';
adoQuery1.ExecSQL;
adoQuery1.Close;
adoQuery1.Open;
```

Here's the error I get: `Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.`

Anyone here who knows how to handle quoted string within the ADO SQL text? Appreciate any help.

Comment: FYI, `ExecSQL; Close; Open;` makes absolutely no sense. Second, use `Open` for `SELECT` - `ExecSQL` is for queries that do not return a resultset (insert, delete, update).

Comment: Noted @KenWhite . Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code very similar to yours works for me:

```
if Pos('%', Article) > 0 then begin
    SQLCmd := 'SELECT d0301000.id_partstd ' +
              'FROM d0301000 ' +
              'WHERE (d0301000.Type = ''AF'') ' +
                'AND (d0301000.Part_Nbr LIKE :Part_Nbr)';
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := SQLCmd;
    ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Part_Nbr').Value := Article;
end
else begin 
    .....   // Code removed for simplicity
end;
ADOQuery1.Open;
```

You are using `ExecSQL` for a SELECT statement. Replace it with `Open`.

Comment: Thank you so much @fpiette. It works! Appreciate the quick help.